# Has anyone recast Aristotle's Law of Noncontradiction as a law of recontextualization?

Tags: logic, aristotle, buddhism, dialetheism, context

Aristotle's Law of Noncontradiction (LNC) is translated in a variety of ways:

> Let us next state what this principle is."It is impossible for the
> same attribute at once to belong and not to belong to the same
> thing and *in the same relation*"; and we must add any further
> qualifications that may be necessary to meet logical objections. [[*Met*, IV.1005b, italics added](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0052%3Abook%3D4%3Asection%3D1005b#:%7E:text=Let%20us%20next%20state%20what%20this%20principle%20is.%22It%20is%20impossible%20for%20the%20same%20attribute%20at%20once%20to%20belong%20and%20not%20to%20belong%20%5B20%5D%20to%20the%20same%20thing%20and%20in%20the%20same%20relation%22%3B%20and%20we%20must%20add%20any%20further%20qualifications%20that%20may%20be%20necessary%20to%20meet%20logical%20objections)]

and

> It is impossible that the same thing can at the same time both belong
> and not belong to the same object and *in the same respect*, and all
> other specifications that might be made, let them be added to meet
> local objections [ [*Metaphysics*, Book Γ, 1005b19–23, quoted from *Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy*, italics added](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/contradiction/#:%7E:text=It%20is%20impossible%20that%20the%20same%20thing%20can%20at%20the%20same%20time%20both%20belong%20and%20not%20belong%20to%20the%20same%20object%20and%20in%20the%20same%20respect%2C%20and%20all%20other%20specifications%20that%20might%20be%20made%2C%20let%20them%20be%20added%20to%20meet%20local%20objections%20(1005b19%E2%80%9323))].

and

> It is impossible that the same thing belong and not belong to the same
> thing at the same time and *in the same respect*. [[*Met*, 1005b19-20, quoted from Wikipedia, italics added](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_noncontradiction?useskin=vector#:%7E:text=It%20is%20impossible%20that%20the%20same%20thing%20belong%20and%20not%20belong%20to%20the%20same%20thing%20at%20the%20same%20time%20and%20in%20the%20same%20respect)].

Nonetheless, in all its translations, the law is always qualified with regard to some *respect* or *relation* or most generally, some *context*. Given this intrinsic qualification, one might recast the LNC as a *law of recontextualization*:

*Any apparent contradiction can be resolved through recontextualization.*

I am aware of one scholar, Brook Ziporyn, that I interpret as having done so, at least implicitly: *[A] statement always brings with it its own way of being true, its own [context], and [contextualizing] is literally unavoidable.* Ziporyn is himself interpreting the philosophy of [Tiantai Buddhism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/buddhism-tiantai/). Here is the quote in context:

> In Buddhist terms, we may say simply that “respects” or “senses” or
> “contexts ” do not have self-natures. They have no single unambiguous,
> true-in-all-contexts boundaries that define contexts as having just
> this set of characteristics and no others. We may see here why it is
> that Buddhist thinkers in particular have an insight into the
> non-ultimacy of the LNC: *the claim that “a thing cannot contradict
> itself” is entirely dependent on how we define a “thing,”* where we
> draw the boundaries between “this” and “something else,” how much of
> the total swath of experience is separated off as one thing as opposed
> to another. That is, we usually define “this thing” as simply “as many
> bits of information as can be experienced consistently and as not
> contradicting each other; where the contradictions start, we ipso
> facto consider a new thing to have begun.” “Same thing” in Aristotle’s
> definition is as problematic as “same respect” and “same time,” and
> for the same reason. “Real entity” and “LNC” are two alternate
> descriptions of the same idea: a real entity is just defined as
> whatever accords with the LNC. *The Buddhist rejection of any fixed and
> unambiguous boundaries for any single entity entails also a rejection
> of the LNC.* Contexts must themselves be contextualized to be the
> contexts they are. Contextual accounts of truths necessitate holism,
> and holism has no non-arbitrary stopping point. The most comprehensive
> holism is self-undermining, as the self-reference and self-inclusion
> paradoxes show. Conventional Truth cannot be kept safe from the
> ravages of Ultimate Truth, i.e., the fact that the latter negates the
> truth of every Conventional Truth. The contexts which warrant
> Conventional Truths are infected by the undermining of them that we
> see initially in the universal Ultimate Truths. But not to worry: all
> this means is that there are infinite Conventional Truths, infinite
> Ultimate Truths, and, thus, infinite paradoxes.
>
> The Tiantai claim is that parameterization is intrinsic to the simple
> act of making two statements, even two non-contradictory statements,
> about “the same” thing. To play with a very old Chinese example, if I
> have a white horse before me, and I say “it is white” and also “it is
> a horse,” the sense in which it is white is not the sense in which it
> is a horse. What makes it true that it is white is not what makes it
> true that it is a horse. In one sense it is a horse, in one sense it
> is white. “Horse” is the answer to one kind of question about it,
> while “white” is the answer to another. It is in the context of
> someone ’s concern with color that it is correctly (usefully,
> successfully) called white. It is in the context of someone ’ s
> concern with animal taxonomy (say) that is it correctly (usefully,
> successfully) called horse.
>
> So it cannot be that “there is an absolute truth,” and “there is no
> absolute truth” are meant “in the same way,” for *no two statements can
> ever be meant in “the same” way*, if “same ” is meant to signify
> something radically distinct from “different.” The point is that *a
> statement always brings with it its own way of being true, its own
> parameters, and parameterizing is literally unavoidable*. (italics added)
>
> *What Does the Law of Non-Contradiction Tell Us, If Anything? Paradox, Parameterization, and Truth in Tiantai Buddhism*

Where Ziporyn uses the term *parameterization* I use the term *contextualization*. I mention Ziporyn's interpretation of Tiantai Buddhism not to defend it (though I do), but to demonstrate that at least one philosopher has highlighted the LNC's fundamental reliance on the caveat of context (aka respect, relation) and has at least gestured towards understanding the LNC as a claim about using recontextualization as a means of resolving any apparent contradiction.

So with all of that as background, has any other philosopher made a similar argument? Has anyone argued or gestured towards an argument that the LNC can be understood as being a claim about the power of (re)contextualization to avoid contradictions?

Comment: +1 for Buddhism. The world would be much better off if we just threw everything else away and started there.

Comment: Most western philosophy and popular logics including classic or intuitionistic logics which rejects LEM treat LNC simply as unqualified context-free same as law of identity. Perhaps Graham Priest's dialethism and some paraconsistent logic would reject or limit LNC under some (re)contextualization. Philosophers like Wittgenstein, Quine, and Davidson all expressed similar views, such as Davidson's *Reality Without Reference* could be said to reflect and skeptical on the conventional contextualization power...

Comment: @DoubleKnot Those are the 'usual suspects' I've been investigating! The subtext for my question is that my Law of Recontextualization (LoR) can be interpreted as a less pejorative gloss of trivialism. As such, Priest would definitely reject it. As for W, Q & D, I completely agree that they would be sympathetic to LoR, but none, to my knowledge, actually expressed anything closely resembling it. Cites to the contrary much appreciated. I'll look at Davidson's RWR to see if there's any explicit resonance. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed they all mainly reflect on the ground of philosophy of language as some game or meaning semantics, it's not that clear to what extent LNC at the logic core is to be shaken. But if a (linguistic) world is actually without reference, then even law of identity cannot be contextualized or recontextualized...

Comment: There seems to be a rationalistic leap from "impossible to belong and not belong to the same thing at the same time and in the same respect" (negative claim) to "can be resolved through recontextualization" (positive claim). One can certainly argue the latter, but it will be more than simply "recasting" Aristotle's more modest assertion. Wittgenstein, for example, contemplated impossibilities that cannot be so "resolved", at least not by us. Ziporyn outlines why our recontextualizing powers are not entirely up to the task. Hegel argued similarly with respect to Heraclitean flux.

Comment: @DoubleKnot, formal logics don't ignore the effects of context; they fold those effects into the formalism so that anything that might effect the truth of a proposition must be included in the proposition.

Comment: Possibly related: In a inconsistent Axiomatic Framework, anything can be proven true. So, at least in formal logic, there is always a recontextualization that makes something true.

Comment: I don't think it's special that LNC "relies on context" insomuch as all the principles of logic "rely on context." P(x) → P(x) is only logically necessarily true when both P holds of x in exactly the same respect, and so on. Each occurrence of the same propositional letter, predicate, and variable should refer to only one state of affairs, set of things, and one thing, etc.
Contextualization as a means of solving paradoxes is a popular approach. Take the Liar's paradox. Tarskian solution, axiomatic theories of truth, and many others can all be seen as parametrizing the paradoxical sentence.

Comment: @DavidGudeman 'White horse is horse' is true by merely the semantic context of horse contained in the subject, and 'white horse is not horse' could be said to be true follows recontextualization in terms of white. Ergo these 2 attributes or essences can be completely separated and can you find a real thing outside of a formal symbol which only has one attribute situated in a single context?...

Comment: @DoubleKnot, that's not formal logic.

Comment: @Conifold, I agree that there is the possibility that I've made a leap in the recasting, but I think it is an open question to explore more deeply. For example, the law of conservation of energy can be recast from a negative formulation ("energy can't be created or destroyed") to a positive one ("changes in energy are always transformations of energy").

Comment: You can surely turn any negative claim into a positive, but the positive recast here would only be "contradictory properties must belong to different things or to no thing, or, if to the same thing, at different times or in different respects". It would only signal a problem, not give us a guarantee of recontextualization that resolves it. This is akin to the difference between "pure existence" and constructive solution. Indeed, the 'correct' resolution might be dissolution, that the entire conception behind the contradiction is misguided, not just improperly contextualized, etc.

Comment: @Conifold, Thanks for sharpening the issue. I think it is fair to interpret your "must belong" "problem statement" formulation as logically entailing my recontextualization solution. This is because the problem statement contains the structure of the solution: there must be different things, times, or respects to which the apparently contradictory properties actually belong, so they can be discovered / determined through appropriate analysis. Once discovered, they constitute a recontextualization. Again, this is akin to how we apply the Law of Conservation of Energy.

Answer (score 3):

Fuzzy logic maps degrees of truth over the otherwise conventional logic membership relations (MATLAB - What Is Fuzzy Logic?):

https://youtu.be/__0nZuG4sTw

Call it recontextualization or whatever term.

Comment: Thanks for this insight. I agree that fuzzy logic is a particular way of 'recontextualizing' (ie via changing the truth value weight) to avoid all contradiction. See this example of how fuzzy logic recontextualization can avoid the Liar Paradox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox

Answer (score 3):

Resolving a contradiction is an issue that arises in dialectic: there is an apparent inconsistency in my/your/their beliefs and I want to resolve it. In the *Metaphysics* Aristotle isn't coming from the standpoint of resolving contradictions, and so he talks about dialectic only incidentally. For resolving contradictions we should instead consult Aristotle's works on dialectic, where we indeed find the "law of recontextualization" stated by Aristotle himself (*Sophistic Refutations* [19](https://archive.org/details/worksofaristotle01arisuoft/page/n595/mode/1up?view=theater)) as the solution to the fallacy of ambiguity:

> At the start, then, one should reply with regard to an ambiguity, whether of a term or of a phrase, in this manner, that 'in one sense it is so, and in another not so.'

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for your answer! I wasn't aware of this part of Aristotle's work. So Aristotle himself arguably understood the relationship between the LNC and my Law of Recontextualization. So I wonder if he would have embraced my recasting. He seems to come close in SR 20: 'It is evident also that not all refutations depend upon ambiguity as some people say they do.' Aristotle seems to suggest that at least some people embrace something like my Law of Recontextualization. I wonder who they were!

Comment: @NickGall Interesting point. As I understand, you want to say that what I pointed to as the Law of Recontextualization isn't really a universal law because Aristotle applies it only to one specific fallacy and only "some people" say that ambiguity is the one and only fallacy. But possibly you could still say it's a universal law (though I haven't examined this closely). Ambiguity is contradiction arising from words and phrases with multiple meanings, but since your Law of Recontextualization isn't limited to that case possibly all solutions of fallacies could be viewed as (re)contextualization

Comment: Glad you like it. And I agree with your way of 'saving' the Law of Recontextualization'. I'm in the process of reading a paper that addresses these issues, 'What is a Sophistical Refutation?' It's pretty slow going for me. I'll report back my takeaways from it when I finish it.
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/David-Botting/publication/257520243_What_is_a_Sophistical_Refutation/links/5f2069a2a6fdcc9626ba457a/What-is-a-Sophistical-Refutation.pdf